# What does this command do in Kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I'm a beginner at this and I have started the overthewire.org war games in order to learn.

I just need to know that what this command do?

```
file ./*
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)

Comment: Type `man file` and start reading ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` command determines a file's type. You can see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)), and per the article:

> `file` is a standard Unix program for recognizing the type of data contained in a computer file.

For further reading, see [the Linux manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html). So, `file ./*` identifies the types of all the files in the current directory (`./` is the current directory, and `*` selects all the files). Use `man file` to see the manual for the command.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. I had the idea of what file command does but was confused with the ./* thank you very much

Comment: then you need to read about bash and [globbing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)/[wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)